# Unit test NG2 service call that uses .map()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following function in a service -

```
get(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get( 'endpoint', {}, false )
        .map( this.getJson );
}
```

In my component I call this function to make the API call - Everything is fine at this point

When I come to test it, I have the following so far -

```
it( 'expect service.get() to exist', inject( [ ExampleService ], ( service: ExampleService ) => {
    spyOn(service, 'get').and.callFake(function(){
        return resp;
    });

    expect( service.get() ).toBeTruthy();
} ) );
```

This passes, however I need to test the .map() - Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was going about this the wrong way.

I was mocking the Http module myself - Queue [MockBackend](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html)